# Tricking Git, slow internet Connection

Tags: git, github

I have a bit of an issue and I need to trick git.

Basically I have a repo that I share with another programmer who is in a place where internet is very slow.
This repo has a lot of images, and they rarely change.
Anyway so I shared this repo with the other programmer, and he downloaded it, after which something happened and I had to close the repo down.
I did some minor code changes on the repo and uploaded it again, and I want the other programmer to be able to work on it. now he has a copy of that repo but some files are out of sync, but the images are the same ( 95% of the repo size is images ). His local copy doesn't have any git symbols.
How can I have him trick git into thinking that he just has an old version of the remote repo, so he can get only the code changes but not have to download the entire repo again?

To Clarify:

the new repo  is not the same as the old repo, its the same codebase, but not the same commit objects or hashes.

Comment: What do you mean with “had to close the repo down”? If it’s still the same repository (same commit objects, with the same hashes etc.), then there shouldn’t be a problem. The other programmer can just fetch from the repository and will only get the new stuff.

Comment: no its not the same repo, its the same codebase, but not the same commit objects or hashes.

Comment: Well if the repositories don’t share common Git objects (commits), then you’re pretty much out of luck. If the images are identical, it might be possible to just add the new remote to the repository and fetch from and it Git might be able to skip the images for which it already has the blob objects. Not sure if that really works though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the content is the same, then all he needs is the commit objects.  That's easy.

```
mkdir for-my-buddy
git rev-list --all \
        | git pack-objects for-my-buddy/pack
```

Email him the contents of that directory, have him drop those into .git/objects/pack, git branch -m / git tag -f his refs onto yours, and you're done.

edit: you can experiment safely and dirt-cheap by doing

```
git clone -s path/to/real/repo path/to/playground/repo
```

and doing all the work in the playground.  When you're satisfied, push the work over.

Comment: ... and if that's still too large by enough to justify a few hours' work, just enough information to accurately reproduce the commits will compress a whole lot better, because the sha's can be stripped here and reproduced there.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to rsync your directory with his. A git repo is just a bunch of files - it doesn't have any runtime logic that keeps state.

If the repos are technically completely different and you don't care about the history data of the old repo tell him to delete the `.git` directory before rsyncing with yours. If you care about the history of the old repo tell him to make a backup of his directory and then delete the `.git` directory before rsyncing his with yours.

Comment: yes well he did delete the .git directory, so now I should just RSYNC with mine? after that I assume he should be able to do a git fetch? to get latest?

Comment: Yes, should be able to in theory. You guys may need to edit the `.git/config` file if you have git config changes specific to you but otherwise it should work.

Comment: he has a codebase with the .git directory deleted, I have a repo thats on github, which is almost the same code as his codebase but with minor changes, that repo is brand new as well.